# How to display data looping in 3 td table

Tags: php, loops

i want to create looping data in 3 td table

i want looping like this image

[image]

This is my code

```
<table>
<tr>
          <?php $sql="select * from study";
                        $rs=mysql_query($sql);
                        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){ ?>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>

                <td width="30%" align="left" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="minat" value="<?php echo $row1['studyid']; ?>" />
                  <?php echo $row1['studyname']; ?></td>

                <td width="30%" align="left" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="minat" value="<?php echo $row1['studyid']; ?>" />
                  <?php echo $row1['studyname']; ?></td>

                <td width="30%" align="left" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="minat" value="<?php echo $row1['studyid']; ?>" />
                  <?php echo $row1['studyname']; ?></td>
              </tr>
                    <?php } ?>

                      </table>
```

Help Me Thank's you  all

Comment: A row inside of a column? That's a paddlin'.

Comment: Hint: use **[modulus](http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic)** operator and logic.

Comment: First please remove the extra opening table tag (or properly close it, if it is intended to be nested within the parent table). Also, be sure to clean up your tabs/indentations for easier reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, check if it should add a tr beginning or end.

This is just a sample code:

```
<?php $sql = "select * from study";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$i = 0;
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    if($i%3 == 0) echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type="checkbox">$row[studyname]</td>";
    if($i%3 == 2) echo "</tr>";
    $i ++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Actually, if you use div it will be very easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php $sql="select * from study";
$i = 0;
$rs=mysql_query($sql);
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{ 
$i++;
?>
<td width="30%" align="left" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="minat" value="<?php echo $row1['studyid']; ?>" />
<?php echo $row1['studyname']; ?></td>
<? if($i % 3 == 0) { ?>
</tr><tr>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```